# randomize contents of tableview cells

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, random, core-data

I what I have below is the code that loads string from core data named title. What I would like to do is have a func that randomizes the order of the way all the names are displayed on the tableview cell every time the button is pressed. If possible also save the new order.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let song = songs[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "songCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = song.title
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: You need to show relevant code. The cell code isn't relevant. The relevant code is your button code and the code that loads the `songs` array.

Comment: Where does the original order come from? That is, how is `songs` ordered before you shuffle it?

Answer (score 0):

A func that randomizes the order of the way all the names are displayed on the tableview may look like:

```
func buttonTapped() {

    // The following two lines are populating songs from Core Data, you may use some wrapper framework.

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Song")
    let objects = try? self.context.execute(fetchRequest) ?? []

    // Update the model behind data source with the shuffled list of songs and reload the table.

    self.songs = objects.shuffle()
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```